# How to get a material ui (next) dialog with top and bottom margins that grows beyond the screen

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm struggling with a layout issue.

What I want?

A modal dialog that grows vertically, beyond the screen, that it is centered horizontally and vertically, that has a minimum margin on top and bottom.

Is not on the documentation of MUI?
The "official" method on MUI shows a dialog that has a scroll inside the content of the dialog showing the action button always on screen. I don't want that. I know it may sound against Material Design guidelines, but in our app this makes sense.

Did you googled this?
Yes

What I have now?
I have the dialog growing beyond the screen, and the scroll on the background, which is good, but I don't have top / bottom margins, it grows until it reaches the top 0 (see screenshot 2).

For better describing this issue I will show two important states: the dialog that is smaller than the viewport (A) and the dialog that os bigger than the viewport (B).

Screenshot 1 - state A - desired state
[image: State A: small dialog - desired state]

Screenshot 2 - state B upper working acceptable with no top / bottom margins
[image: State B: big dialog - upper current state with no margin top]

Screenshot 3 - state B upper desired
[image: State B: big dialog - upper desired state]

Screenshot for state A with issue adding top / marginTop / paddingTop
[image]

You can play with this example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lxw7ylxy8z

So, as you can see, if I use a marginTop or a top on the paper element from MUI, or a paddingTop in the root element of the MUI Component dialog property, then I have a problem with state A, the small dialog, that now looks non vertically centered.
Also the bottom margin just doesn't work on state B.

I'm considering things like [EQCSS](https://elementqueries.com/) or do some calculations based on the computed size of the dialog, but I feel like it should be a better option using just CSS and flexbox. The extra issue with this is that I can't insert elements within the MUI Hierarchy, or at least I don't know how.

Hope someone can help me with this,
If you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was pretty easy, I just added two small fixed height div, one at the top and one at the bottom.

See here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/1rnj7kv3mj

Accepting this solution for now.